# Is there a way to use a typescript interface with optional keys, but then concretize that the keys are there?

Tags: typescript, type-inference

This code:

```
interface Dog {
  name?: string;
  size?: number;
}

const entity: Dog = {
  name: 'max',
}

const name: string = entity.name;
```

Causes this error:

> Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

I can avoid the error by removing the `entity` type:

```
interface Dog {
  name?: string;
  size?: number;
}

const entity = {
  name: 'max',
}

const name: string = entity.name;
```

But then I lose the auto-complete feature.

Is there a way to win both? To have autocomplete, and let the code know which keys are there based on the initializer?

E.g. using `Required<Dog>` isn't a good solution because I don't want to initialize `size`. The real use-case I have actually has a much bigger interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Typescript >= 4.9

in typescript 4.9 we can use the [satisfies operator](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9-beta/#hamilton):

```js
interface Dog {
    name?: string;
    size?: number;
}

const myDog = {
    name: 'bello',
} satisfies Dog;

const dogName: string = myDog.name;
```

## Typescript < 4.9

What I do is to define a generic identity check function that can be used for any interfaces:

```js
function identityCheck<T = never>() {
  return <I>(input: I & T) => input as I;
}
```

then create a concrete check-function for the `Dog` interface:

```js
const dogIdentity = identityCheck<Dog>();
```

finally use it to create the constant:

```js
const myDog = dogIdentity({
    name: 'bello',
})
// name is of type string
myDog.name.slice();
```

[Typescript Playground Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAJgUzLKBPAwgCzQgGsAeAFUQF5Ew0A3NAJwD4AKASkQG8BYAKESImaKCCZJSASXYwwABxBQAXIimIAZInJcqLZAqWIAhgGc1AbgEBfAQLlRmwYxDSIAInADmPAUKFgxgC2aAD8qqZQTHJeVoL%20pjAAXmGqYCBBAEbMcbb8AhAIkYgo3lLomDA41MgVWHiEJKSeXuwccQVFUIhB2C01pV7lGPVsfPEBwWiqAOTZADbzcDMANDYcAr0tAHSBIdum8zCunBZAA)

Comment: So cool! Thank you. I like how this solution is more generic than `captain-yossarian` so I can just use `identityCheck` whenever I need it. I'm going to call it `partialChecker`.

Answer (score 1):

You can infer it with help of extra function:

```js
interface Dog {
    name?: string;
    size?: number;
}

type IsValidDog<Animal> = Required<Dog> extends Animal ? Animal : never;


const builder = <Animal extends Dog>(animal: IsValidDog<Animal>) => animal

/**
 * Ok
 */
const result = builder({
    name: 'max',
})

result.name // ok
result.size // expected error


const result2 = builder({
    name: 'max',
    size: 42
})
result2.name // ok
result2.size // ok

/**
 * Error
 */

const result3 = builder({ name: 'Sharky', unknown: 2 }) // expected error
const result4 = builder({ nAme: 'Sharky', size: 2 }) // expected error
const result5 = builder({ name: 'Sharky', size: 2, surname: 'Doe' }) // expected error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCIHsDmyDeAoZQ5EOAWwgH4AuZAZzClEwG4CjbgAvSmkAV1IAjaKwC+ePGACeABxQBJWgDU4AG2AATDJgA8AQRDBSagHzIAvMgBKEAI59gUCBp3azEAB6QQG2sgNGasgU-obGqsi8EABuIhJ4COgg9MiCDqoa0BbI+mFBnt6+aFgmABRweao0iirqWli5gaomAJQWZhVNEgD0AFS9BL3IAPIA1oPdCUkpTrR8qmDZacAZ0KX4RMRkEDQA5MYeuwA0eKItErPzYAB0JOTI3d3I6OOXC9cc3A9PnnIIkBpkNAoOgoPFEslFm8wAAmJbpTJQdZsQh3HbIfZwQ4nTafdEAFhhp3O0Jht2232erwgcwWZLxlJePX6g2QAFEoCCwchepMppDkNCAMzwlaI9Zbch7ADKAAs4FBRlJjsg+CBRiB0AB3EA0OFnSm-CD-ZxAzmg-kzGlXfGi1ZInDEPRSjFyhVKlV4vXIA2PIEeP4As1cy1Q60LACsdvFjrRMvliuVRzoXHRMOTcygcYxGAgux9bT9RpNgOBFqAA)

`builder` function expects/allows exact a `Dog` object. It allows use less properties, because all of them are optional but it disaalow any extra properties to bu used, see `result5`.

`IsValidDog` - checks whether `Dog` with all required props extends passed object interface. If you pass an object with some extra properties, this check will fail.

You can find more validation techniques in my [blog](https://catchts.com/validators)