# TypeScript: autocomplete but disable inferring

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Suppose we have a type:

```js
type A = {
  a1?: string;
  a2?: number;
  a3?: boolean;
}
```

And a variable with this type for autocompletion:

```
const b: A = {
  a1: "test";
}
```

`b` now has type `A`, but I want to infer this type:

```
type B = {
  a1: string;
}
```

Is it possible?

---

I need to create function with signature like this:

```js
type A = {
  a1?: string;
  a2?: number;
  a3?: boolean;
}

const b = build<A>(() => {
  return {
    // autocompletion from type A should works
    a1: string;
  }
});
```

where type of `b` should be:

```js
type B = {
  a1: string;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `satisfies` operator merged into TS 4.9, the straightforward approach with TS 4.9 (slated for November 2022) is:

```ts
type A = {
  a1?: string;
  a2?: number;
  a3?: boolean;
}

const b = {
  a1: "test"
} satisfies A;
```

See:

- ["satisfies" operator to ensure an expression matches some type (feedback reset) #47920](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47920)
- [Typescript satisfies](https://medium.com/@cefn/typescript-satisfies-6ba52e74cb2f) article
- [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.0-dev.20220829&ssl=9&ssc=15&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeBYAUFKBDAjAfgC4oBnYAJwEsA7AcwG51MsAmQqKgVwFsAjCMhhmwBmNjwD24gDYQsVQQF906AMbiqpKDwTJG2HEQBEwCKUPoFJLMArEAZhVOxBQA)

Comment: Wow. This is really cool to know that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When I understood your question right, you want to to this

[Playground Exmaple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=20&pc=6#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeBYAUFKBDAjAfgC4oBnYAJwEsA7AcwG51MsAmQqKgVwFsAjCMhhmwBmNjwD24gDYQsVQQF906AMbiqpKDyJxEqIbiIAiYBFJH0StOgBmHKiuAV1UCgBMIVJ6ADCACwgVAGsAHgAVBHYIADd%20AD4ACgBKZEYoMghgDjIqKBCASUTqMA5gInyoADIoMJT4ONcqEuBsYih8xWU0NQ0WnhxI909vEH9A0JhEpIT9JhxjU3NLJK6AelX2cQB3KHUpEGwBijbiP23c6mxS8QBaNS4wGVN0foA6XC7P6zQgA):

```js
type A = {
  a1?: string;
  a2?: number;
  a3?: boolean;
}

const b: A = {
  a1: "test"
}

function identityCheck<T = never>() {
  return <I>(input: I & T) => input as I;
}

const b1 = identityCheck<A>()({
  a1: "test"
})

// now only a1 is shown in auto-complete
b1.a1
```

see also: [Is there a way to use a typescript interface with optional keys, but then concretize that the keys are there?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69417966/1041641)

Comment: The solution was simple, but smart. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Based on TmTron answer I created a class based solution cuz I don't like how currying looks:

```
class SomeBuilder<S = never> {
  constructor() {}

  build<T>(callback: () => S & T) {
    return callback as () => T;
  }
}
```